# foreach INSERT into Mysql DB is really slow, specially when inserting over 100K records and over

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

How could I make this code faster. It's fine when I insert 100 records into my database but it takes really long time when I insert let's say 500K records.
I've tried to use implode in my code but it's not working.
Code seems to have two foreach loops, one inside the other, but I can't find a way to make it work, does anyone has an idea? 
My framework is codeigniter.

Here's what the code looks like:

```
<?php  
 function Add_multiple_users($values)
{
    $err = '';
    foreach($values as $rows)
    {
        $clientQuery = 'INSERT INTO
                            client
                            (
                                admin_id,
                                create_time
                            )
                            VALUES
                            (
                                "'.$this -> session -> userdata('user_id').'",
                                "'.date('Y-m-d H:i:s').'"
                            )';
        $clientResult = @$this -> db -> query($clientQuery);
        if($clientResult)
        {
            $client_id = $this -> db -> insert_id();
            foreach($rows as $row)
            {
                $attrQuery = 'INSERT INTO
                                    client_attribute_value
                                    (
                                        attribute_id,
                                        client_id,
                                        value
                                    )
                                    VALUES
                                    (
                                        "'.$row['attribute_id'].'",
                                        "'.$client_id.'",
                                        "'.addslashes(trim($row['value'])).'"
                                    )';
                $attrResult = @$this -> db -> query($attrQuery);
                if(!$attrResult)
                {
                    $err .= '<p class="box error">Could not add attribute for<br>
                            Attribute ID: '.$row['attribute_id'].'<br>
                            Client ID: '.$client_id.'<br>
                            Attribute Value: '.trim($row['value']).'</p>';
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $err;
}
?>
```

Here's what I've tried:

```
                $attrQuery = "INSERT INTO client_attribute_value (attribute_id, client_id, value) VALUES ";

                $vls = array();
                foreach($rows as $row) {
                    $myattribute_id = $row['attribute_id'];
                    $myclient_id = $row[$client_id];
                    $myvalue = addslashes(trim($row['value']));
                    $vls[] = " ( '$myattribute_id ', '$myclient_id ', '$myvalue ')";


                  $attrQuery .= implode(', ', $vls);

                  $attrResult = @$this -> db -> query($attrQuery);
```

Client Table sample:
[image: client table sample]

client_attribute_value Table sample:
[image: client_attribute_value]

Comment: Didn't work the batch insert? Or what issue did you have with it? BTW, what is long time? minutes? hours? 500k rows is quite a good amount of data

Comment: 500K records could take up to 2hrs on my server. I think the code I tried hungs because I added an array()., because the first foreach loop inserts the data into the client table, but the second for each loop stops the code.   I'm just trying to make the insert into DB faster using the implode option

Comment: how many attributes do you have per user? I would first rewrite the script and using prepared statements with placeholders. Prepare the statement **before** foreach, bind parameters and execute the statement inside the loop. In your inner foreach do a single insert with multiple values.

Comment: it depends, some times there can be 2,4,6,10, etc. They are created according to the csv list to be loaded into database

Comment: If it's usually less than 100 then I see no problem with a single insert for all attributes of an user.

Comment: less than 100 is ok, it only takes like 5mins, but sometimes I'll have a customer that wants to upload a file with 100K records with like 3 attributes per client [first, last, email, etc]. This is when my server slows down, inserting 100K+ records.

Comment: @chap You misunderstand me. I meant: less than 100 attributes per user shouldn't be a problem with `INSERT ... VALUES (< first attribute row>), (<next attribute row>), ..., (<last attribute row>)` instead of the series of queries in your inner foreach. So you have only two queries per user. It should speed up the whole a bit.

Comment: as @VMai suggest, and I also asked you above, ;D, what happened with the insert batch? you said you tried, but it didn't work? I've speeded from minutes to seconds inserts of several thousands with it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own Question, hope this helps someone else in the future.

In the model .php file of the codeigniter/framework add this:

```
$this->db->trans_start();

   MY CODE

$this->db->trans_complete();
```

Problem Solved.  :)
It speed up my INSERTS records to database approx. 15K records in 30secs.

Comment: How did this help you?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you are making multiple connections with the database, try to open one and preserve it's resource opened for all changes, then you close it only at the end of the process.

Comment: Do you have an idea how to do that, my application is on a Codeiginiter Framework

Comment: I don't know this framework, but, if you have a look at it's code (if you have an uncompressed code) maybe you'll find a mysql_connect statement, wich returns a resource, try to preserve this resource and avoid unnecessary recurrent connections